# Skin and suit too shiny and plastic when import .fbx to Unity ( images added )

Tags: unity-game-engine, fbx

I tried to import model ( very new to Unity, .fbx format bundled with texture and animation ) in Unity 3D ( 5.3.2 version ) and it works but skin and other stuffs look more shiny than on texture or 3d studio as it looks like on image below:

(I have one default directional light in Unity and have tried with different values but cannot achieve as on texture ).

[image]

and I have texture from .fbx below:

[image]

What should I do to make to skin and other stuff look like on texture ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking to adjust the material and shader. Not the light nor the texture.

You need to tell Unity how you want the light to interact with your object. Right now, it thinks the object is "Shiny" and glossy. I assume you want something more flat/toony.

Check out these offical guides for more information: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Materials.html
https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/graphics/materials

Answer (score 1):

In my case it improved setting the `Shader` to some `Nature` value.
[image]